# Как сделать поиск по сайту?

Tags: c#

Возможно ли использовав (Windows Form) создать программу с поисковой строкой. А именно, пользователь вводит в поисковой строке некий вопрос интересующий его и когда вопрос был задан, чтобы данные шли от сайта WikiHow, но не в браузере эта вся процедура, а в программе. Если да, то как можно привязать к программе контент WikiHow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно. В общих чертах в теле метода обработчика нажатия на кнопку поиска из вашего приложения нужно поместить запрос, отправляемый на HTTP API сайта WikiHow. Запрос отправляйте с помощью [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx)

Полученный результат можно распарсить при помощи какой-нибудь библиотеки, осуществляющей парсинг HTML-контента. В общем случае контент будет содержаться в строке, которую вы получите при помощи `WebClient` после отправки запроса. Если API позволяет получить данные в формате JSON, то парсите результат при помощи [JObject](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm).

PS: Я бы советовал использовать технологию [WPF](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) вместо Windows Forms

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Надо будет разобраться по этапно. А чем WPF отличается WF? WPF именно для клиентской части?

Comment: WPF - более современная технология разработки графических интерфейсов. Сейчас майкрософт активно продвигаент UWP. Если хотите написать кросс-платформенное приложение (чтобы работало и на планшетах и на телефонах с Windows 10), то можно разрабатывать под UWP. По сути, все три технологии, будь то UWP, WinForms или WPF предполагают, что всё работает на клиентской машине.

Comment: Спасибо большое за информацию!!